# sqlite native library in Android returns disk I/O error

Tags: sqlite

I use cmake and sqlite native library in my Android app and I am getting error 10 : disk I/O error after a simple select clause on one table.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_3
```

After doing some experiment, I found out that I won't get this error if I limit the size of my select clause.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_3 LIMIT 100
```

this makes me wonder if this issue has something to do with the length/size of the data returned from the query (100 seems to be the magic number/threshold, I have 200 records in the table)

[image: an exmaple of a record in table_3]

All the columns are string/text, among them column_4 is considered the largest in size(about 15000 characters)

I am not familiar with SQL and wonder if there is any limit around the size of the data returned?

Comment: No, there is no limit on the amount of data returned. I'd suspect that you have an issue with a corrupted database or index, or an issue with a bad sector on your hard disk.

Comment: @KenWhite, this happened multiple times and on multiple devices..

Comment: *disk I/O error* is pretty clear. It's one of the issues I mentioned before. If it's happening on multiple devices, then it seems more likely that a corrupt database or index was deployed. If it was an issue with the amount of data, it wouldn't be a disk I/O error that was generated.

Comment: @KenWhite, if the database is corrupt, I am wondering why I am able to get the results back with limit 100 but not all of them.. is there a way to tell if it is corrupt or not?

Comment: Because the point of corruption is beyond the area where the first 100 rows are located would be one reason. Did you try Googling *corrupt database SQLite* to see what information is available about detecting and/or repairing them?

Comment: @KenWhite, I will take a look, thanks